# MYSQL Different timezone in shared hosting

Tags: mysql, timezone

i have a problem with mysql timezone.
Mysql timezone is +0:00
and i need to set the timezone to +7:00

here is my code

```
function db_connect(){
        global $dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname;
        $link_id = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword);
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        if (!$link_id){
            $MYSQL_ERRNO = 0;
            $MYSQL_ERROR = "Connection failed to the host $dbhost";
            return 0;
        }
        else if(!mysql_select_db($dbname)){
            $MYSQL_ERRNO = mysql_errno();
            $MYSQL_ERROR = MYSQL_ERROR();
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            mysql_query("SET SESSION time_zone = '+7:00'");
            return $link_id;
        }
    }
```

i have set the timezone every connect to the database.
But when i want to insert data, the timezone was go back to +0:00
someone please help me.
Thank you very much

Comment: Why are you setting `time_zone` globally and not just for the session?

Comment: yes, i have use SET SESSION time_zone = '+7:00'. but still now working

Comment: How are you determining that "*the timezone was go back to +0:00*"?

Comment: Yes, when i already call function NOW() for one time, the time was go back to +0:00 again.

Answer (score 1):

Use command

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+7:00'");
```

Refer to the [Details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: use comment `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` to see that timezone has changed or not

Comment: that's good, friend. the timezone of session go to +7:00.
But the problem is, when i have mysql qeury like this "insert into category values (NULL,"Food",NOW(), "I",NOW()); 
the second now() was go back to system time again

Comment: I don't know were is the problem but why you don't use php `date()` instead of mysql `NOW()`? you can use as this `$now = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() );` and `"insert into category values (NULL,"Food",$now, "I",$now);"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a COMPLETE example, for Argentina.

```sql
SET GLOBAL time_zone = "-03:00";
```

you only need to change the "-03:00" for your timezone and run that command like a simple query, even in PhpMyAdmin.